# cvsroot not taken into account or incorrect

Tags: centos, cvs

On CentOS release 6.7 (Final) :

I've set cvsroot using

```
set CVSROOT=:pserver:jay:pwd@hostname.fr:2401:/cvsdata/BUS-2010
```

where jay is my susername, pwd the password, and hostname.fr the hostname. Then I've launch an add:

```
cvs add YD
```

and I get the error message :

```
cvs add: CVSROOT may only specify a positive, non-zero, integer port (not `2401:').
cvs add: Perhaps you entered a relative pathname?
cvs add: in directory .:
cvs add: ignoring CVS/Root because it does not contain a valid root.
cvs add: No CVSROOT specified!  Please use the `-d' option
cvs [add aborted]: or set the CVSROOT environment variable.
```

So I've made a change removing the ':' after the port number :

```
set CVSROOT=:pserver:jay:pwd@hostname.fr:2401/cvsdata/BUS-2010
```

and it seems taken into account :

```
$ echo $CVSROOT
:pserver:jay:pwd@hostname.fr:2401/cvsdata/BUS-2010
```

But I still have the same error :

```
$ cvs add YD
cvs add: CVSROOT may only specify a positive, non-zero, integer port (not `2401:').
cvs add: Perhaps you entered a relative pathname?
```

What did I miss?

Comment: The bit between `:pserver:` and the hostname is meant to be a username but you have `jacq-82396:dev`. Is this correct?

Comment: @BurhanAli : jacq-82396:dev is username:password. I use this CVSROOT configuration in a java program and it works fine. It's just using this in command line that doesn't seem to be accepted.